# Will there be a way to avoid duplicate records after joins in this scenario?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have 3 tables I am trying to join on a field that will be the same in all tables, but the tables aren't related relationally.

```
TableA :
Account_Number | merchant_name | sale_date
123456789      | merchant 1    | 04-22-2016
123456789      | merchant 2    | 03-25-2016
123456789      | merchant 3    | 02-26-2016

TableB :
Account_Number | authorization_date | authorization_amount
123456789      | 04-22-2016         | 23
123456789      | 03-5-2016          | 55

TableC : 
Account_Number
123456789
```

Since these tables aren't relationally related, they only have a similar column value that each table could have, i'm confused on how this output could ever be different than showing 6 records in the response, one for each record in the table which will be giving a unique record for each value in each table.

If I wanted to have a response showing null values in each table, is this possible?  If I outer join the tables, I was supposed to see null values for fields that don't exist, but this doesn't seem to work.

Maybe I am confused on how the outer joins work, but it was my understanding that all records are returned from all tables, but NULL is returned for fields that don't exist.  Below is the query I have and the response, which is showing 6 records total, which is accurate but is adding other table data in the record which is making it a bit confusing and hard to reduce duplication.

Query :

```
SELECT A.merchant_Name, A.sale_date, B.authorization_date, B.authorization_amount, C.account_number
FROM (TableA AS A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB AS B ON A.[account_number] = B.[account_number]) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableC AS C ON A.[account_number] = C.[account_number]
WHERE (((A.account_number)='123456789'))
ORDER BY A.sale_date, B.authorization_date;
```

Output :

```
  merchant_Name|sale_date|authorization_date|authorization_amount|acct
    merchant 3   02-26-2016    03-05-2016              55           123456789
    merchant 3   02-26-2016    04-22-2016              23           123456789
    merchant 2   03-25-2016    03-05-2016              55           123456789
    merchant 2   03-25-2016    04-22-2016              23           123456789
    merchant 1   04-22-2016    03-05-2016              55           123456789
    merchant 1   04-22-2016    04-22-2016              23           123456789
```

The need is to have a response for all three fields, if values exist based on the account_number.  Is something like the below possible?

```
merchant_name | sale_date | authorization_date | authorization_amount | acct
merchant 3    | 02-26-2016|       null         |      null            | null 
merchant 2    | 03-25-2016|       null         |      null            | null
merchant 1    | 04-22-2016|       null         |      null            | null
  null        |  null     |     03-05-2016     |      55              | null
  null        |  null     |     04-22-2016     |      23              | null                  
  null        |  null     |     null           |      null            | 123456789
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get any NULL values with this query using OUTER JOINS because the joins are on the account number, and each table has records that match.

You can get the result you need using a UNION ALL query, which gets the results of separate queries and adds them together, one after the other.

Try this query:

```
SELECT A.merchant_Name, A.sale_date, NULL AS authorization_date,
NULL AS authorization_amount, NULL AS acct
FROM tableA A
WHERE A.account_number = '123456789'
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, b.authorization_date, b.authorization_amount, NULL
FROM tableB B
WHERE B.account_number = '123456789'
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL NULL, NULL, NULL, C.account_number
FROM tableC C
WHERE C.account_number = '123456789';
```